# Is there a searchable list of communities on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, search, communities-list

Many times I've tried to find a community to ask a question in, but it's somewhat difficult to wade through the page of 'squarish' buttons for the community entry points. Is there some place or some way to get a text list of them (to make it easier to search)? Or am I missing it somewhere?

Comment: You mean like [this](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list#traffic)?

Comment: You can turn that page into a list view, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a list of communities on https://stackexchange.com/sites. There you could use the find command of your web browser but, maybe the best way to search for a site is to use the search on https://stackexchange.com/. It will return a list of questions across the SE network including the icon and name of the site that each question belongs to. Searching for questions is better because some site names could leed to confusion, i.e. [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com) gets a lot of questions about developing them but that are off-topic on that site.

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  I musta missed it in the documentation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can search for a site by clicking the Stack Exchange icon in the upper right  and searching for a site name in the box like so:

[image]

If there's nothing in the box, it's a list of all sites, sorted alphabetically.

(Note that in the above picture I scrolled down a little so you can see more results.)