# Ability to search for sites, not just for questions?

Tags: feature-request, search, communities-list

From time to time I'll find myself with a question to ask, but no clarity on which Stack Exchange site I should ask it. Alternatively, I'll know that a certain site exists, but can't remember the name, only the topic. So, I'll want to execute a search for the appropriate site.

Problem: the main Stack Exchange search bar ("Search all sites") searches for questions, but does NOT search for sites. The results are only questions, and it's pretty clear that the containing site's topic doesn't play any role in their ordering. I sometimes have to go absurdly deep in the results to get to a question in the clearly relevant site.

Some examples:

- When looking for the "Gardening and Landscaping Beta" site, searching for "landscaping" first shows the site as the 21st result, but searching for "gardening" doesn't show the site until the 220th result
- When searching for "mathematics", the "Mathematics" site doesn't show up until the 665th result
- When searching for "english language", the "English Language Learners" site doesn't show up until the 268th result, and the "English Language & Usage" site doesn't show up until the 710the result
- When searching for "Linux", the "Unix & Linux" site isn't in the first 1000 results
- When searching for "travel", the "Travel" site isn't in  the first 600 results
- When searching for "cooking", the "Seasoned Advice" site isn't in the first 600 results.

Nobody but a hyper-persistent guy like me would go anywhere near as far down the results list to find these sites, which means there's no practical way for a user to find a relevant site.

Yes, there's a list of all the sites, but given that there are (currently) 173 of them, reading through the entire list trying to figure out which one fits my need isn't helpful.

So, could users have the ability to look for sites, not just for questions?

Comment: The list of sites doesn't fit this need, as it's very long and the  names aren't always clear matches to their topics.

Comment: Did you look at my answer to that question? It's the same as Glorfindel's, therefore I feel it's a duplicate question.

Comment: Seems different to me, but it's your call.

Comment: Thanks to @PolyGeo for editing the [previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314971/is-there-a-searchable-list-of-communities-on-stack-exchange)'s title; it now matches the body much better, and is indeed a duplicate of mine.

Answer (score 3):

This option exists already; click on the Stack Exchange logo at the very right of the top bar. When you scroll down, you'll find a search box:

[image]

Comment: Well, heck. Never saw that before. Thanks.