# Using the "Search all sites" on the "All sites" page does something unexpected

Tags: feature-request, search

I wanted to find the link to the site the name of which I forgot but knew a term it has to do with, so I went to https://stackexchange.com/sites which can be found by clicking "All sites" tab link when you are on the https://stackexchange.com/ page. The search bar on top says "Search all sites", and so I assumed it would do as it says, and not something like "Search on Meta Stack Exchange" like you see above here, on MSE. The result was several thousand questions and answers on all the network sites which contained the search term. For example, try searching for ["gaming"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=gaming) (545'771 results, none related to Arqade.SE on the first page).

Following the principle of least astonishment, I propose to add a search among the names, descriptions and a set of thesaurus words to find the Stack Exchange site one might be looking for, instead of just searching for the entered keyword all over the network.

This is a UX problem basically, and, to clarify, I'm proposing to add a prominent search bar which in no uncertain terms says something that means you will receive search results for the sites on the network, not the posts.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to access beta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340264/easy-way-to-access-beta-sites) - What you did is what you get, the correct way to make such a search is shown in the duplicate. --- See also, another duplicate: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314971/is-there-a-searchable-list-of-communities-on-stack-exchange

Comment: Both linked posts answers the question "How to search for a site", but I'm proposing a new feature here for the page which is specifically named "All sites", and should have an explicit search input prominently displayed on it. I know other ways to search for sites, this is not what I'm asking here.

Comment: It would be nice if you explicitly indicated such in your question itself, to prevent others from also voting to close your question as a duplicate.

Comment: Sonic's comment echos our experience. You title the question and start out with a big paragraph detailing the horror or using Search incorrectly. You find it "astonishing", yet [such functionality isn't unheard of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/) - *that* could (and does have a FR) benefit from the idea. Your question is > 85% "it didn't do what I expected, it did the same thing as it does everywhere else, and **one** (maybe **2**) sentences saying "add a new feature, instead of explaining how the existing ones work".

Comment: I admit that I suck at writing on meta. The years of experience of writing feature requests and bug reports have taught me that too often, no matter how I phrase my posts, they get misunderstood as duplicates of other things or get no reaction. So I do what I can - experiment by trying out new ways. This is yet another attempt and I'm no closer to understanding how to maximize my chances to improve the sites. Thank you for coming to my ted talk :p

Comment: When I read the question title my first thought was "it does something unexpected, it works!"... But of course, search even on just one site is a constant annoyance.